# Add Request Field to CC email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

When starting a workflow it allows me to CC people. When I CC people they do not get the Request put in the email (the Request field states "This message will be sent to the people assigned tasks."). Is it possible to ALSO include the message in the emails sent to the people who are CCd?

This is a SP2013 WF.[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 workflow or SharePoint 2013 workflow? What is the Request field? please provide some screenshots or steps to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design as they have no task to complete on the item.  The individuals in the CC field are only to receive notice, not complete a task, which is what drives workflow.  If you would like to change the message sent by a workflow, you will need to create/modify it in SharePoint Designer.